# Cancel Mouse Out Animation

Tags: css, css-animations

I have a hover effect from a plugin on our wordpress site. I just want it to simply change the image without any transform or transition effects. I have it to where I removed the effects now on Mouse In by changing this (it used to flip horizontally):

```
.ioi-container .ioi-style5 .he-box .he-content {
    transform: none; 
    transition: none;
}
```

The problem that on Mouse Out I can't find the CSS that makes the animation happen. Can anyone point me in the right direction. The development site is here:http://bdi.inventivewebdesign.com/ and the images in question are at the bottom of the page right above the footer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```css
.ioi-container .ioi-style5 .he-box:hover .box-img {
    transform: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Some tips to debug in Chrome

1. Disable the slider animation via JS.
2. Slow down the animation speed in Chrome, Read more https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/inspect-styles/animations
3. Find the hover CSS by simulating hover state in Chrome, Read more, [How to use chrome web inspector to view hover code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5789739/how-to-use-chrome-web-inspector-to-view-hover-code_)

I am sure you will be able to find the correct CSS selector to override like I did :)