# Inspect the HTML Element Which comes only on Hover or Focus

Tags: javascript, html, firebug, web-inspector

i just want to inspect one html code block(for eg: tooltip), which comes only when i focus on the input text box. I am unable to see the properties of the tooltip code block, using web inspector or firebug. Please help me to inspect those htmls which present only on hovering or focusing on some other elements.Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1675405/firebug-how-to-inspect-elements-changing-with-mouse-movements

Answer (score 12, accepted):

On Chrome you can do it like this

[image: Chrome inspect]

See bottom right, you can toggle the element states as you wish

Comment: Nice One Sam. Thanks For the help. It is Working perfectly for anchor tags. I am trying to bring the focus to the input text field, which is not working by this method, could you you please tell me how to do it for the input box?

Comment: It should work for text box input elements too unless the styles are added via JavaScript then I'm not sure the focus trigger on the chrome inspector would work

Comment: I am trying to inspect the tooltip which comes when i put focus on the input text field, the script for the tooltip to come is on javascript.

Comment: Then I don't know, if you can't use the chrome element state you'll have to modify the javascript so the tooltip is always displayed while you're working on it seems to me to be the only solution

Comment: Thank you! Such a simple solution for a longtime annoyance!

Answer (score 2):

Just open it in Chrome and Press ctrl+shift+C .. undock from browser default window and click on search icon !

[image]

Comment: I guess image is missed in the answer.

Comment: Thanks For the help. It coul be more usefull if u explain it in few steps. i am not able to get what u mentioned in the answer.